# Bricked Nexus 7, USB Not being recognised at all

Tags: nexus-7, boot-loop, bootloader, usb-on-the-go

My Nexus 7 all of a sudden stopped sending data through usb OTG and i tried to erase cache through TRWP but ended up deleting the OS. Now I am stuck with a device with no OS. I cannot mount the USB for my computer to recognise it so that I can restore it. I tried ADB sideload but it doesnt load and gets stuck on starting...

If I click on Mount, I cannot click on the USB-OTG box. My computer does have the correct drivers for the USB as it used to work on it before but since the OTG stopped responding to data I am now stuck and cannot push a restore image to the device.  I tried different OTG cables, different computers. None of the computers even detect a device as plugged in. Whether I boot into bootloader or recovery I just cannot get the PC to even acknowledge the fact that something is plugged in. As a result I am just not able to flash it at all. I tried NRT with the soft-brick option but that fails too because it says no adb connectivity.

Any help would really be appreciated.